# If $\sigma=(a_1 a_2 ... a_n)$ and $|\sigma|$ is odd, then what is $\sigma^2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I'm trying to understand the way to infer the power of a permutation.

If $\sigma=(a_1 a_2 ... a_n)$ is a $k$-cycle and $k=|\sigma|$ is odd, then how can I infer what $\sigma^2$ is?

Comment: Well if $\sigma=(a_1a_2\dots a_{2m+1})$ then $\sigma^2=(a_1a_3\dots a_{2m+1}a_2a_4\dots a_{2m})$

Comment: @almagest And why is that?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Look at some examples:

$$\begin{align*}
&(1)^2=(1)\\
&(123)^2=(132)\\
&(12345)^2=(13524)\\
&(123457)^2=(1357246)
\end{align*}$$

There’s a pretty obvious pattern developing here. We can guess, for instance, that

$$(a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5a_6a_7a_8a_9)^2=(a_1a_3a_5a_7a_9a_2a_4a_6a_8)\;.$$

Try to express this pattern in a general form and then prove that it actually holds for all cycles of odd length.

Comment: The leap from such simple examples to the general seems daunting.

Comment: @mavavilj: It seems pretty straightforward to me. Can you at least express it in words?

Comment: I don't understand the proof technique here. Induction over permutations?

Comment: @mavavilj: Before you worry about proof technique, you need something to prove. In other words, the first step is to describe what $\sigma^2$ is when $$\sigma=(a_1a_2\ldots a_{2n+1})$$ for some $n$.

Comment: Why can $\sigma^2$ be generalized? Your examples seem to assume that the cycles are some progressions such as 12345. What about something like $(257)$?

Comment: @mavavilj: I used those examples only because they make the pattern exceptionally clear. Did you look at my example of what happens to a general $9$-cycle?

Comment: Well yeah, but I don't see why it holds. Seems too abstract to me.

Comment: @mavavilj: Just do the multiplication! The permutation $\sigma$ sends $a_1$ to $a_2$ and $a_2$ to $a_3$, so when you apply it twice, it sends $a_1$ to $a_3$. Apply the same reasoning to each member of the cycle.

Answer (score -1):

It has nothing to see with the length of the cycle:
$$\sigma^2=(a_1\,a_3\,a_5\dots a_{2i-1\bmod n}\dots a_{2n-1\bmod n}).$$

Comment: Why the down vote? Isn't the formula exact?